# Remote silent push to activate crashed app

Tags: ios, push-notification

I understand there are several questions about remote silent push when in background. I also understand that a remote push cannot revive an app that the user has quit from the app switcher.

However none of other posts answers these questions:

- When a background app has crashed, can a remote silent push revive it **in the background**?
- When the device is restarted, can a remote silent push start the app back up in the background?

NOTE: the app in question has BLE, location updates and remote notifications all enabled in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a silent push notification can relaunch a crashed app.

No, after a restart, a silent push notification cannot launch the app.

About this last point: there is *very* little you can do before the user unlocks the device after a restart. Try it - you'll notice that you can't even get on *WiFi* until the user has unlocked the device.